# two columns face to face when page breaks

Tags: tables, page-breaking, multicol

I want to make a command for translated text. My wish is to have two columns facing each other : the original on the left and the translated on the right, with the informations about the text beyond.

I have made two kinds of commands, which are working quite well, except when the text is too long, or when there is a page break in the text :

- **\kt** is using the **multicol** package, whith the pagebreak I have the original text on both columns in the first page, and the translation begins on the second page, so they are not in front of each other.
- **\ktt** is using a table environment, but to avoid pagebreak in the table, it will move the translated text further, and not respect the order I want to write in (even with [h!]). In my MWE for instance : I have written

  1. a normal paragraph,
  2. the translated text,
  3. a bold paragraph,

but the document shows the order 1,3,2 (normal, bold, translation) with a big blank.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{relsize}

\newcommand{\kt}[5]{\begin{quote} \begin{singlespace} \begin{multicols}{2}
\smaller \og {\itshape  #4} \fg \vfill \columnbreak #5
\begin{flushright} #2, p. #1, trad. #3 \end{flushright} % normally I have \cite[#1]{#2}
\end{multicols} \end{singlespace} \end{quote}}

\newcommand{\ktt}[5]{%
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{singlespace}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.43\textwidth}p{0.43\textwidth}}
\smaller \enquote{{\itshape #4}} (#2, p. #1) & \smaller #5 (#3)\\  % normally I have \cite[#1]{#2}
\end{tabular}
\end{singlespace}
\end{table}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\kt{PAGE}{BOOK}{TRANSLATOR}{\lipsum[1-2]}{\lipsum[1-2]}

\pagebreak
\lipsum[1]
\ktt{PAGE}{BOOK}{TRANSLATOR}{\lipsum[1-2]}{\lipsum[1-2]}
\textbf{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

I think two kinds of solutions are possible :

- using the **multicol** command, something to force the second columns to begin in front of the first one, even with a pagebreak
- for the table environment, something to allow pagebreak and to force it to follow the order.

I've tried to use the **longtable** package, with this code for **\ktt**, but it doesn't change anything, maybe I'm not using it well :

```
\newcommand{\ktt}[5]{%
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{singlespace}
\begin{longtable}{p{0.43\textwidth}p{0.43\textwidth}}
\smaller \enquote{{\itshape #4}} (#2, p. #1) & \smaller #5 (#3)\\  % normally I have \cite[#1]{#2}
\end{longtable}
\end{singlespace}
\end{table}}
```

Thanks if someone can help.

Two small words :

- **\lipsum** gives me a bracket issue, but I don't have it with normal text instead, so it is not relevant here.
- I have modified the command to avoid the **\cite** for #1 and #2, so that I don't have to add some bibliographic references in the MWE.

**EDIT :**

Thank you Arash and touhami. I've tried diffrent packages, and finally used **paracol**. As the two columns were inserted in a "quote" environment, I needed to use a negative value for **\setlength{\columnsep}{...}**, trying to adjust it to my needs.

But I have new problems now : the two columns were printed **under** the footnotes.

MWE of the columns under the footnotes

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{paracol}

\newcommand{\kt}[5]{
\begin{quote}
\setlength{\columnsep}{-.12\textwidth}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{singlespace}
\sloppy \smaller \og {\itshape  #4} \fg (#2, p. #1) \switchcolumn #5 (#3) % normally I have \cite[#1]{#2}
\end{singlespace}
\end{paracol}
\end{quote}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]\footnote{foo}
\kt{PAGE}{BOOK}{TRANSLATOR}{\lipsum[1]}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

I've seen the problem there : [Footnote problem using paracol package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97088/footnote-problem-using-paracol-package). I've pasted the code given by David-Carlisle in his answer, even if I don't understand it really, and now the footnotes have **disappeared** on the concerned pages.

MWE of the disappeared footnotes :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,final]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{paracol}

\makeatletter
\newbox\mybox
\def\pcol@makenormalcol{%
  \ifvoid\footins 
  \else
\global\setbox\mybox\box\footins
   \fi
\setbox\@outputbox\box\@holdpg
  \let\@elt\relax
  \xdef\@freelist{\@freelist\@midlist}%
  \global\let\@midlist\@empty
  \@combinefloats}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\kt}[5]{
\begin{quote}
%\setcolumnwidth{.1\textwidth,.1\textwidth}[1,2]
\setlength{\columnsep}{-.12\textwidth}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{singlespace}
\sloppy \smaller \og {\itshape  #4} \fg (#2, p. #1) \switchcolumn #5 (#3)
%\begin{flushright}trad. #3 \end{flushright} % normally I have \cite[#1]{#2}
\end{singlespace}
\end{paracol}
\end{quote}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]\footnote{foo}
\kt{PAGE}{BOOK}{TRANSLATOR}{\lipsum[1]}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

**SECOND EDIT :**

It seems to work with touhami's suggestion using :

```
\footnotelayout{m}
```

I hadn't understood well how this command worked, I thought it was working only for footnotes made **inside** the translated text, but in fact, it solved my problem even if the footnote is **outside** my \kt environment.

Thanks !

Comment: In general, there are some packages for this kind of task; check [here](https://www.ctan.org/topic/parallel).  I tried `paracol` and was happy with it.

Answer (score 3):

`multicol` and `longtable` are not designed for such use and `table` environment
don't allow page break.

Here a solution with `paracol` package

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{paracol,lipsum}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}



%\columnratio{.5}
%\columnsep =10pt
\newcommand{\kt}[5]{%
\sloppy
\begin{paracol}{2}
\smaller \og {\itshape  #4} \fg    %  becarful here as \lipsum end with \par
\switchcolumn
#5
\end{paracol}
\begin{flushright} #2, p. #1, trad. #3 \end{flushright}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\kt{PAGE}{BOOK}{TRANSLATOR}{\lipsum[1-2]}{\lipsum[1-2]}


\end{document}
```