# Footnotes problem using paracol package 2

Tags: footnotes, paracol

sorry if this is already explained somewhere but I couldnt find anything.
I'd like the footnotes within my paracol environment to appear not below it but instead at the bottom of my page, like all the others (and ideally also sorted correctly).

In [Footnote problem using paracol package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97088/footnote-problem-using-paracol-package) I've at least found a way to make my footnotes appear - I've implemented the code of the answer (credits to David Carlisle) but my footnotes created in the paracol-environment keep appearing directly after the environment instead of at the end of the actual page (footnotes created before/after the paracol environment appear at the end of the page).

[image]

MWE:

````
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{paracol}

\makeatletter
\newbox\mybox
\def\pcol@makenormalcol{%
  \ifvoid\footins 
  \else
\global\setbox\mybox\box\footins
   \fi
\setbox\@outputbox\box\@holdpg
  \let\@elt\relax
  \xdef\@freelist{\@freelist\@midlist}%
  \global\let\@midlist\@empty
  \@combinefloats}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

some text\footnote{first footnote: before paracol}
\bigskip
\begin{paracol}{2}

table\footnote{second footnote: within paracol}
\switchcolumn
there is some text here
\end{paracol}

\ifvoid\mybox\else\insert\footins{\unvbox\mybox}\fi
\bigskip
some more text\footnote{third footnote: after paracol}

\end{document}```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the code from the other post, and add `\footnotelayout{m}` below `\usepackage{paracol}`.
For details, [read the fine manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/paracol/paracol-man.pdf), section 7.6.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\footnotelayout{m}
\begin{document}
some text\footnote{first footnote: before paracol}
\bigskip
\begin{paracol}{2}
table\footnote{second footnote: within paracol}
\switchcolumn
there is some text here
\end{paracol}
\bigskip
some more text\footnote{third footnote: after paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! In the footnotes of my actual document, footnotes before and within paracol go to _14_ but the footnote numbering starts with _17_ afterwards again. So it skips the numbers _15_ and _16_ (doesnt skip any footnotes). One thing I've noted that I also used exactly two footnotes within my paracol environment. Have any idea about this weird behaviour or should I open a new question?

Comment: @tork Best open a new question, after researching it a bit.